# Webscraping Code / Playwright not filling information into google maps

Tags: python, pycharm, playwright, proxies

I wanted to try some coding for webscraping my favorite hobby - guitars.

This code seems like it should get me there but doesn't.

Here is some of the error code:

```
playwright._impl._api_types.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator("xpath=(//div[@role=\"article\"])[1]")
```

tons of research and CHAT Code Interpreter. Clueless at this point.